# Template arguments can't be omitted when specializing this function template

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, function-templates

In C++, Explicit specializations of function templates is like:

```
template<typename T> return_type fun_name();
template<> return_type fun_name<int>(){/* blabla */}
```

The `<int>` in the above example is called template argument. Sometimes `<int>` can be ommitted because compiler can do [Template Argument Deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction)

But I can't find out why [Template Argument Deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) failed in the following example:

```
//-------------failed case-------------
template <typename T>
struct deduce{
    typedef T* type;
};


template  <typename T>
typename deduce<T>::type fun1();

template  <>
typename deduce<float>::type fun1<float>() //error if no "<float>" after fun1
{

}

//------------now the "Template Argument Deduction" works------------
template <typename T>
struct some_struct{
    T* p;
};

template  <typename T>
some_struct<T> fun2();

template  <>
some_struct<float> fun2() // no error even if no "<float>" after fun2
{

}
```

If no `<float>` is after fun1, The error message is:

```
error: template-id ‘fun1<>’ for ‘float* fun1()’ does not match any template declaration
```

Maybe the compiler think the type(`deduce<float>::type`) marked by `typename` is less reliable than normal types ?

Comment: with `deduce<float>::type`, `T` is non deducible. You might have several class T which satisfy your type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me provide an example of why non-deduced contexts are non-deduced. Template deduction is basically trying to match on the input. If I had:

```
template <class T> void foo(T );
```

and I call `foo(4)`, that's easy. `T=int`. If I call `foo('x')`, `T=char`. These are easy substitutions to make. If `T` is nested somewhere in the type, like:

```
template <class T> void bar(std::vector<T> );
```

that's still totally doable. If I call it with a `std::vector<std::vector<float>>`, `T=std::vector<float>`. Still no problem.

Now consider this one:

```
template <class T> void baz(typename X<T>::type );
baz(4);
```

What's `T`? In all our previous cases, there was one obvious choice for `T` that was deduced directly from the argument passed to the function template. But here, that's not the case. We have an extra layer of indirection - we need to deduce a `T` to make a type `X<T>` whose member typedef `type` is `int`. How do we find such a thing?

Now let's say we had this:

```
template <class T> struct X { using type = T; };
```

Ok now it's easy right? `T=int`? Well, not so fast. For the primary template, that would work in this case. But what if there was also this specialization:

```
template <class T> struct X<T*> { using type = T; };
```

(that is, `X` is `std::remove_pointer`). Now we're in a situation where `T=int` works... but `T=int*` also works. And maybe there's some other type out there that also works for `int`. How do you pick the right one?

This problem - picking a template parameter in the nested-name specifier of qualified-id - is really hard and has no obvious path forward. So the compiler just won't take a path forward. It's a non-deduced context. `T` will never be deduced in the call to `baz`, the caller has to provide it:

```
baz<int>(4); // ahhhhh, ok, you wanted X<int>::type
```

---

Back to your question. `some_struct<T>` is a deduced-context, but `typename deduce<T>::type` is a non-deduced context. I hope it's clear now why the former works but the latter doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for you counter-example, which gives a clear reason for the case mentioned in [Non-deduced contexts](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts)

Answer (score 0):

> Maybe the compiler think the type(`deduce<float>::type`) marked by `typename` is less reliable than normal types ?

It has nothing to do with `typename`, the point is that `deduce<T>::...` is a nested-name-specifier; which belongs to [Non-deduced contexts](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts):

(emphasis mine)

> In the following cases, the types, templates, and non-type values that are used to compose P **do not participate in template argument deduction**, but instead use the template arguments that were either deduced elsewhere or explicitly specified. **If a template parameter is used only in non-deduced contexts and is not explicitly specified, template argument deduction fails**.
>
> 1) The nested-name-specifier (everything to the left of the scope resolution operator ::) of a type that was specified using a qualified-id:

So, for

```
template  <>
typename deduce<float>::type fun1()
```

`deduce<float>::type` (i.e. `float*`) will be used to deduce type `T` for `deduce<T>::type`, but `T` won't be deduced, template argument deduction fails. You have to explicitly specify it as `float`.

Comment: A quick example demonstrating the reason for this restriction would be nice.

Comment: Thank you for indicating the exact place of this behavior in  [Non-deduced contexts](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts). I just didn't have the courage to fully read this doc to find out answer.